# Collision Detection works but has small glitch?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have written a small program that when implemented stops a small square passing through a larger rectangle.

When the `collision()` function is called it checks whether or not the shapes are colliding. Currently it does the following:

- When the square is moving `up` towards the shape, it doesn't pass through.
  (like it should)
- When the square is moving `down`, towards the shape, it doesn't pass through.
  (like it should)
- When moving `right`, towards the shape, it doesn't pass through. (but it moves up one key
  press)
- When moving `left`, towards the shape, it doesn't pass through. (but it moves left by one key press and up by one key press) (See picture)

[image: glitch]

Here is my `collision()` function:

```
if     (sprite_Bottom +y_Vel <= plat_Top    ){return false;}
else if(sprite_Top    +y_Vel >= plat_Bottom ){return false;}
else if(sprite_Right  +x_Vel <= plat_Left   ){return false;}
else if(sprite_Left   +x_Vel >= plat_Right  ){return false;}
//If any sides from A aren't touching B
return true;
```

Here is my `move()` function:

```
   if(check_collision(sprite,platform1) || check_collision(sprite,platform2)){ //if colliding...
    if     (downKeyPressed ){ y_Vel += speed; downKeyPressed  = false;} //going down
    else if(upKeyPressed   ){ y_Vel -= speed; upKeyPressed    = false;} //going up
    else if(rightKeyPressed){ x_Vel -= speed; rightKeyPressed = false;} //going right
    else if(leftKeyPressed ){ x_Vel += speed; leftKeyPressed  = false;} //going left
   }
   glTranslatef(sprite.x+x_Vel, sprite.y+y_Vel, 0.0); //moves by translating sqaure
```

I want the `left` and `right` collisions to work the same as the `up` and `down`. My code uses the same logic for each direction so I can't see why it does this...

Comment: `if     (sprite_Bottom +y_Vel <= plat_Top    ){return false;}` shouldn't all of these be `if     (sprite_Bottom +y_Vel + speed <= plat_Top    ){return false;}` or something like that.

Comment: `x_Vel` is the position of the `glVertex` and `speed` is the amount it moves by key-presses, so I don't think so, no. If you did that, the square would move further inside the platform each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first check the corner of your sprite for collision. And then if your platform is thicker than your sprite, no further checking is required. Otherwise check whether each side of your sprite collides with the platform.

```
if ((plat_Bottom <= sprite_Bottom + y_Vel && sprite_Bottom  + y_Vel <= plat_Top)
    && (plat_Left <= sprite_Left + x_Vel && sprite_Left + x_Vel <= plat_Right))
    // then the left-bottom corner of the sprite is in the platform
    return true;

else if ... // do similar checking for other corners of the sprite.
else if ... // check whether each side of your sprite collides with the platform

return false;
```

Comment: Ah, good idea. I didn't consider the corner pixels. I will try that now.

Comment: There are some other possible issues. E.g. What happens if the speed is greater than the thickness of the two objects in the direction of travel?

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be because you are adding your speed to your velocity after you check the collision.

This is an issue because you are testing an **older** version of your velocity during your collision. You are then adding your `speed` to the velocity which could move the sprite to be in collision. If you are going to add the speed to the velocity **after** the collision, then you also need to incorporate the speed into the collision algorithm.

Try this in your `collision()` function:

```
int xDelta = x_Vel + speed;
int yDelta = y_Vel + speed;

if     (sprite_Bottom +yDelta <= plat_Top    ){return false;}
else if(sprite_Top    +yDelta >= plat_Bottom ){return false;}
else if(sprite_Right  +xDelta <= plat_Left   ){return false;}
else if(sprite_Left   +xDelta >= plat_Right  ){return false;}

//If any sides from A aren't touching B
return true;
```

Comment: This makes sense and I think I understand what you're saying. I have just tried that, but then it doesn't collide at all. I must be implementing it wrong. I think it's because `x_Vel` is actually the `vertex` coordinate position and I'm updating the position each time.

Comment: @Reanimation `x_Vel` being the coordinate position makes things a bit different. What may help is to output some debug text on your screen which display the current `x` and `y` position of your sprite. Then you can see exactly what they are when they collide. This may help you to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Reanimation No problem. Please let us know how you get on.